# jQuery offset() returning wildly incorrect values in Safari only

Tags: jquery, css, safari, position, offset

I'm trying to get the top offset values for a set of elements on my page. I'm running through each element and logging its top offset value like this:

```
$(elements).each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var offset = Math.floor($(element).offset().top);

    console.log(offset);
}
```

In Firefox, that correctly gives me these values:

```
458, 1023, 1625, 2274, 2746, 3072, 3398, 3823, 4388, 4930
```

But in Safari, I get:

```
460, 718, 976, 1318, 1799, 1918, 2036, 2254, 2512, 2746
```

The reported offset of the first element is basically the same between both browsers, but then Safari completely diverges from there. And the rest of Safari's values are totally illogical: for example, in an `800px` tall window, it reports the second element's top offset as `718px` even though it's actually completely offscreen.

If I manually measure where the top of each element appears in Safari, I get the same values as what Firefox reports. So the page is in fact rendering the same in both browsers, but Safari is just reporting completely different `offset()` values.

(I've also tried using `position()` instead of `offset()`, and I see the same disparity: the first value is correct in both browsers, and then Safari's values are completely off).

I unfortunately can't share my actual code, so in absence of that, what could cause Safari alone to be off by so much?

Comment: From what I can see, this affects any inline-element without content. You have to change the span-element to any block element or adding display: block; to the span-tag

Comment: The elements are already block level, actually (they're floated `div`s).

Comment: Please add a complete testable sample with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I set a `min-height` on the elements, equal to the height that the elements are already rendering at, then Safari reports the correct `offset()` values.